# If the equation $\alpha x^2+4\gamma xy+\beta y^2+4p(x+y+1)=0$ represents a pair of lines. Find the range of $p$ in terms of $\alpha,\beta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

> For $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$ with  $0<\alpha<\beta$, if
>    $$\alpha x^2+4\gamma xy+\beta y^2+4p(x+y+1)=0$$ 
>   represent a pair of lines. Then which one is right?
>   
> (a) $p\in[\alpha,\beta]$
>   
> (b) $p\leq \alpha$
>   
> (c) $p\geq \alpha$
>   
> (d) $p\in(-\infty,\alpha]\cup [\beta,\infty)$

Try: Camparing the equation

$\alpha x^2+4\gamma xy+\beta y^2+4px+4py+4=0$  with general equation of conic

$ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ we have

$a=\alpha,h=2\gamma,b=\beta, g=2p,f=2p,c=4p$

Now if conic represent pair of lines, Then $h^2-ab=0$

So $4\gamma^2-\alpha \cdot \beta=0$

Now How can i relate $p$ with $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

I am struck at that point.

could some help me , Thanks

Comment: That’s not the condition for the equation to represent a pair of lines. It’s the condition for a (possibly degenerate) parabola.

Comment: $\begin{vmatrix}\alpha&2\gamma&2p\\2\gamma&\beta&2p\\2p&2p&4p\end{vmatrix}=-4p(4\gamma^2-4p\gamma+\beta p+\alpha p-\alpha\beta)=0$ is the condition for degenerate conic. If we assume $p\neq 0$, then we get $p=\frac{4\gamma^2-\alpha\beta}{4\gamma-\alpha-\beta}$.

Comment: @Mathlove please explain me How i solve.Thanks

Comment: @Jan Magnus Yes i have missed it. How can I solve it from $\displaystyle p=\frac{4\gamma^2-\alpha \beta}{r\gamma-\alpha-\beta}.$

Comment: @Durgesh Tiwari : I've deleted my previous comment since I have not seen carefully the title saying "Find the **range** of $p$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer shows that there are no correct options and that the range of $p$ is $$p\in\bigg(-\infty,0\bigg]\cup \bigg[\beta,\infty\bigg)$$

---

For the condition "a pair of lines", we have two cases to consider :

- intersecting lines
- parallel lines (including "coincident lines")

Here, let

$$\begin{align}\Delta&:=\begin{vmatrix}
    \alpha & 2\gamma & 2p \\
    2\gamma & \beta & 2p \\
    2p & 2p & 4p \\
    \end{vmatrix}=-4p((\alpha+\beta-4\gamma)p+4\gamma^2-\alpha\beta)
\\\\J&:=\begin{vmatrix}
    \alpha & 2\gamma  \\
    2\gamma & \beta  \\
    \end{vmatrix}=\alpha\beta-4\gamma^2
\\\\K&:=\begin{vmatrix}
    \alpha & 2p  \\
    2p & 4p  \\
    \end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}
    \beta & 2p  \\
    2p & 4p  \\
    \end{vmatrix}=4p(\alpha+\beta-2p)
\end{align}$$

Let us consider a necessary and sufficient condition in each case (see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticCurve.html) for the details) :

The equation represents intersecting lines
$$\begin{align}&\iff \Delta=0,J\lt 0
\\\\&\iff p((\alpha+\beta-4\gamma)p+4\gamma^2-\alpha\beta)
=0,\ \alpha\beta-4\gamma^2\lt 0
\\\\&\iff \begin{cases}p=0,\ \alpha\beta-4\gamma^2
\lt 0\\\\\quad\text{or}\\\\
p=\frac{4\gamma^2-\alpha\beta}{4\gamma-\alpha-\beta},\ \alpha\beta-4\gamma^2\lt 0\end{cases}\end{align}$$

The equation represents parallel lines (including "coincident lines")
$$\begin{align}&\iff \Delta=0,\ J=0,\ K\le 0
\\\\&\iff p((\alpha+\beta-4\gamma)p+4\gamma^2-\alpha\beta)
=0,\ \alpha\beta-4\gamma^2=0,\ p(\alpha+\beta-2p)
\le 0
\\\\&\iff \begin{cases}p=0,\ \alpha\beta-4\gamma^2=0
\\\\\quad\text{or}\\\\
\alpha+\beta-4\gamma=0,\ \alpha\beta-4\gamma^2=0,\ 0\lt p\le\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\end{cases}
\\\\&\iff p=0,\ \alpha\beta-4\gamma^2=0
\end{align}$$
(the latter case doesn't happen since then we get $\alpha=\beta$ which contradicts $\alpha\lt \beta$.)

Now, suppose that $p=\frac{4\gamma^2-\alpha\beta}{4\gamma-\alpha-\beta}=\alpha$. This implies $(\alpha-2\gamma)^2=0$ from which $\gamma=\frac{\alpha}{2}$ follows. From $\alpha\beta-4\gamma^2\lt 0$, we get $\alpha\beta-4(\frac{\alpha}{2})^2\lt 0$ implying $\beta\lt\alpha$ which contradicts $\beta\gt\alpha$.

So, we see that $\alpha$ is not included in the range of $p$.

Since every option includes $\alpha$, there are no correct options.

---

In the following, let us find the range of $p$.

Let us consider the case where $p=\frac{4\gamma^2-\alpha\beta}{4\gamma-\alpha-\beta}$ and $\alpha\beta-4\gamma^2\lt 0$.

If $4\gamma-\alpha-\beta\lt 0$, then $p\lt 0$.

If $4\gamma-\alpha-\beta\gt 0$, then $p\gt 0$, and we have
$$p\ge \beta\iff \frac{4\gamma^2-\alpha\beta}{4\gamma-\alpha-\beta}\ge\beta\iff (\beta-2\gamma)^2\ge 0\quad\text{which indeed holds}$$

Finally, let us show that there always exists $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ such that $$\small p\in\bigg(-\infty,0\bigg)\cup \bigg[\beta,\infty\bigg)\quad\text{and}\quad p=\frac{4\gamma^2-\alpha\beta}{4\gamma-\alpha-\beta}\quad\text{and}\quad \gamma\in\left(-\infty,-\frac{\sqrt{\alpha\beta}}{2}\right)\cup\left(\frac{\sqrt{\alpha\beta}}{2},\infty\right)$$

Let $f(x)=\frac{4x^2-\alpha\beta}{4x-\alpha-\beta}$. Then, we have
$$f'(x)=\frac{4(2x-\alpha)(2x-\beta)}{(4x-\alpha-\beta)^2},\qquad f\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)=\beta$$
with
$$\small f\left(\pm\frac{\sqrt{\alpha\beta}}{\sqrt 2}\right)=0,\quad f'\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)=f'\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)=0,\quad -\frac{\alpha\beta}{2}\lt\frac{\alpha}{2}\lt\frac{\sqrt{\alpha\beta}}{2}\lt\frac{\alpha+\beta}{4}\lt\frac{\beta}{2}$$

Considering the graph of $y=f(x)$ and noting that $0$ is included in the range of $p$, we see that the range of $p$ is 
$$\color{red}{p\in\bigg(-\infty,0\bigg]\cup \bigg[\beta,\infty\bigg)}$$